# Jenkins not running properly as service from Virtual drive

Tags: jenkins

We have created virtual drive using 
    subst d: c:\ddrive
Then we run jenkins as on d drive from command line
    java -jar jenkins.war
it works fine but same setup convert into service then this is not working fine
by giving error as a cannot create directory d:/my-app/checkout

Comment: Does it have priviledges to write to disk? The service that you created? the user under which the jenkins service is running, try changing the user in the service with an admin username. That will give you a hint if it works fine after providing the admin credentials in the service.

Comment: yes , it have right to write on disk , as i have created virtual drive by doing run as administrator , and created service from same command prompt i.e doing run as a administrator. but still it giving me the error , i know it regard with permition but  unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried providing the service an admin account to run with? I am sorry, this isnt an answer to the question, but i couldnt paste the image in the comments.

[image]

Comment: yes , I have tried it also, But stil it is not working , as there is one post about this issue which tell it may not work..i.e http://support.microsoft.com/kb/180362                                          are u able to run it?